# Using locale (language+country) in URL for Symfony2

Tags: symfony, localization, locale

I'm building an international website in Symfony2. My URL looks likes this:

www.test.com/en_HK

This should display english text and prices in HongKong dollars. The english text part is already working. Is there a Symfony function available to get the country-code from the locale?

The locale contains the "languagecode_COUNTRYCODE". Or should i write some lines of code the distract the countrycode from the locale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no function to do this directly because locales can be 2 letters:

**ex.** en, fr, de

SonataIntlBundle provides some ISO Code expansion, but not what you're looking for

http://sonata-project.org/bundles/intl/master/doc/reference/locale.html

The [Locale](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/locale.html) component comes close, with that you can do:

```
$countryCodes = Locale::getCountries('en_HK');
```

It should be fairly trivial to write a service to do this:

```
class CountryCodeExtractor
{
    function fromLocale($locale)
    {
        if(strlen($locale) == 4){
            return substr($locale, -2);
        }
        else throw new \Exception("Invalid locale passed");
    }
```

something similar to that. Obviously you'll want better validation of the input locale.